# How to store 2 more data in a session with Django 1.3?

Tags: django

I'm making a shopping mall site with Django 1.3 for studying Python and Django. The following is my model.

```
class categories(models.Model):
    cat_no = models.IntegerField() # Category number
    cat_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class items(models.Model):
    item_no = models.IntegerField()
    cat_no = models.ForeignKey(categories)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_size = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    item_img = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class customers(models.Model):
    cust_no = models.IntegerField()
    cust_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class orders(models.Model):
    order_no = models.IntegerField()
    item_no = models.ForeignKey(items)
    cust_no = models.ForeignKey(customers)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    order_date = models.DateTimeField('Ordered Date')
```

I want to store cust_no, item_no, and cat_no in a session when user click a "Add to Cart" button. If user clicks to add 2 more items to the cart, how can I do this with one session data?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the manual about [How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). All you have to do is use request.session like a normal dictionary in your view.